# Prove A is a subring of $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A the set of all 2x2 matrices that follow the format:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & a-b \\ a-b & b \end{pmatrix} \quad a,b \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

How do I prove it's a subring? I know I have to prove it's closed under subtraction and multiplication. Is there an easier way to show this?

Answer (score 2):

$A = \{ a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad | \quad a, b \in \mathbb Z \} $.

This pretty much already shows that $A$ is closed under subtraction. If we use $x$ and $y$ for the two matrices shown in the expression above, you only need to show that $x\cdot x$, $x \cdot y$, $y \cdot x$ and $y \cdot y$ are in $A$, which should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Close under subtraction and multiplication is an easy enough test for a 2x2 matrix :)

Edit to answer comment:

**Closed under subtraction:**

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & a-b\\
a-b & b\end{array} \right)
- \left(\begin{array}{cc}
c & c-d\\
c-d & d\end{array} \right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a-c & (a-b)-(c-d)\\
(a-b)-(c-d) & b-d\end{array} \right)
$$

which clearly has the required form.

**Closed under multiplication:**

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & a-b\\
a-b & b\end{array} \right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
c & c-d\\
c-d & d\end{array} \right)
&=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
ac + (a-b)(c-d) & a(c-d)+d(a-b)\\
(a-b)c + b(c-d) & (a-b)(c-d)+b*d\end{array}\right)\\
&=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 a c-b c-a d+b d& a c-b d\\
a c-b d&a c-b c-a d+2 b d
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}\\
$$

which (slightly less clearly) has the required form.

Comment: I've tried to do it with two general matrices but I think I keep confusing it somehow. I can't get them to work out correctly

Comment: @user338113 I edited my answer.

Comment: You just illustrated why it is better to approach the problem "my" way! :-)

Comment: @mathguy indeed!